# Update External Systems from Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4

a bit new to Dynamics CRM and trying to find the best way to update external systems **in real time** when specific entities are created or updated in Dynamics CRM 4.0 or 2011.  What I've gathered thus far is that my best option is to

1. Write a web service for the downstream LOB system.
2. Write a custom workflow activity that calls the web service and register the plugin inside CRM.
3. Attach the custom workflow activity to a record created / updated trigger on the underlying entity that I want to receive updates for.

Am I on the right track or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have seems a pretty sound design and is probably the way I would approach it.

If you need synchronous behaviour (not sure how real time your real time is here) you might want to consider plugins (different from custom workflow activities) as these can be registered to run synchronously.

Other than that you could have your downstream system read the records from CRM on a frequent, scheduled basis - you can use the modifiedon field to see which records have changed since the last read.